# How to use Completable Future to make External API calls?

Tags: java

I assume there have been a lot of occurrences where one would need to call an external RESTful service based on a List of values.

```
    List<Integer> products = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
```

Now for each of these productId, I would like to call an external endpoint in parallel.
Something along the lines of :

```
    List<CompletableFuture<Products>> futureProducts = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Integer id : products){
    futureProducts.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getExternalApiResponse(id)));
    }
```

How would on go about converting this

```
    List<CompletableFuture<Product>> futureProducts;
```

to

```
    List<Product> completedProductInformation;
```

when all the calls have been completed successfully.

```
    List<Product> productInformation;
```

How would one achieve this using completable futures ?

I guess what I am asking is, How does one wait for all the calls to complete , and then obtain the result in the form of a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and you can handle other businesses in the stream after join.

```
futureProducts.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Just a question , can we say for sure that join  is a non blocking operation ?